# Find the value of a such that F(a) achieves its minimum value

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Find the value of a such that $F(a)$ achieves its minimum value.

$$F(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left|\sin x - a\cos x \right| dx $$

I'm trying to use following fact to solve the problem but then I need to find a bounded linear functional $f$ such that $f(\cos x)=0$ and I don't know how to construct such linear functional.

Let $X$ be a normed space, $f \in X^{*}$, $f$ is not $0$ and $L=$ker $f$, then $d(x,L)=\dfrac{\left| f(x) \right|}{\left|\left|f\right|\right|}$  $\forall x \in X$

For calculus approach, I tried to differentiate the function $F(a)$ and set the derivative equal to zero, but I don't know how to differentiate $\left|\sin x - a\cos x \right|$ with respect to $a$, and I think even I can differentiate it, the derivative $F'(a)$ is not zero.

So anyone could help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

$F(0) = 1$, and for $a<0$ you have $\sin x -a \cos x > \sin x$ everywhere except at $\pi / 2$, so the minimum is achieved for some $a>0$. (There WILL be a minimum, because as $a \to +\infty$, $F(a) \to +\infty$ as well. Then: for $a>0$ there is exactly one $x$ in $[0, \pi /2]$ where the integrand vanishes; write the integral as the sum of two integrals that will no longer have absolute values in them. Then you will be able to easily compute the integrals, and therefore $F(a)$, set $F'(a) = 0$ and solve. If you find one point where $F'$ is undefined, include that in your "search for the point of minimum" as well. Please write back if you run into further difficulties.

Comment: I still can't solve it. I used the following differentiation rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dx = f(x,a(x))-f(x,b(x))+ \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f_{x}(x,t) dx$$
$F(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left|\sin x -a\cos x \right| dx = \int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}a} -\sin x +a\cos x dx + \int_{\tan^{-1}a}^{\pi/2} \sin x -a\cos x dx$
\begin{align*} 
F'(a) &= \int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}a} -\sin x +\cos x dx + \int_{\tan^{-1}a}^{\pi/2} \sin x -\cos x dx\\
      &= (\cos x - \sin x)\Big|_{0}^{\tan^{-1}a} -(-\cos x - \sin x)\Big|_{\tan^{-1}a}^{\pi/2}\\
      &= 2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Then I set $F'(a)=0$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}=1$, which is impossible.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\sin x$ with respect to $a$?

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake.